# C++/Assembly pushing arguments onto the stack for function call

Tags: c++, assembly, stack, x86-64, cpu-registers

i have a special case where i need to push arguments onto the stack **one at a time** and then call a function which takes a callable as an argument and pass those arguments that were pushed to the stack to the callable/function. to solve this i created a few functions in assembly to push arguments onto the stack and call a function passing those arguments. however it seams to work but my code started breaking in weird places whenever i made calls to other functions inside the callable passed to CallFunction.

i need this function to take any callable. any help would be much appreciated.

please note that std::bind and other similar functions are not an option. each argument needs to be pushed onto the stack one at a time using a function call and i need to be able to call functions between calls to PushArg and CallFunction should return the return value of the function it executes.

What ive tried:

saving the stack pointer at the beginning of the call and restoring it before i return (current state)

creating my own stack in memory for storing arguments (too complex and messy and not as efficient as just using the registers and existing stack. would like to avoid if possible)

Code:

```
.data
FunctionPointer QWORD 0
ReturnPointer QWORD 0
StackPointer QWORD 0

.code
ALIGN 16

FT_StartCall PROC
    mov [StackPointer],rsp
    ret
FT_StartCall ENDP

FT_PushIntPointer PROC
    pop ReturnPointer
    push rcx
    push ReturnPointer
    ret
FT_PushIntPointer ENDP

FT_CallFunction PROC
    ;save return address in Memory
    pop ReturnPointer
    mov FunctionPointer,rcx
    pop rcx
    pop rdx
    pop r8
    pop r9
    push r9
    push r8
    push rdx
    push rcx
    call FunctionPointer
    mov rcx,0
    mov rdx,0
    mov r8,0
    mov r9,0
    mov rsp, [StackPointer]
    push ReturnPointer
    ret
FT_CallFunction ENDP

END
```

C++:

```
extern "C" void* __fastcall FT_CallFunction(void* Function);

extern "C" void __fastcall FT_PushIntPointer(void* ArgOrPointer);

extern "C" void __fastcall FT_StartCall();

int ADD(int first,int second){

return first+second;

}

int main(){

FT_StartCall();

FT_PushIntPointer(3);

FT_PushIntPointer(2);

int res = FT_CallFunction(ADD);

return res;

}
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: The C calling convention mandates the stack pointer be preserved. So you can't have a `PushIntPointer` that pushes arguments on the stack and returns with a changed stack pointer. The compiler in the caller function may very well assume `rsp` is unchanged and access variables relative to it. Also, calling convention mandates stack pointer be 16 byte aligned.

Comment: As Jester says, you're mucking with the stack in a way that can't be communicated to the compiler/compiled code.  Also, your global variables are neither thread safe, nor reentrant, and do not support recursion.  Maybe copy parameters to an alternate, thread/reentrant safe location, then copy them back to the real stack upon making the actual call.  Otherwise, without further motivation as to what you're trying to accomplish, hard to brain storm on what might work for that.

Comment: Also on windows you have the shadow space, you are effectively putting things there but that area is transient.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense okay, think i got it. will try some things and report back.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone agrees, you are delving into UB territory with this code, but it does have some experimental value, I guess.

You should consider allocating your own private stack for something a bit more robust.

This bit of code:

```
pop rcx
pop rdx
pop r8
pop r9
push r9
push r8
push rdx
push rcx
```

Does nothing, besides scrambling rcd, rdx, r8 and r9.  You should remove it.

The same goes for this pîece of code:

```
mov rcx,0
mov rdx,0
mov r8,0
mov r9,0
```

Did you try something like this?

```
FT_CallFunction PROC
    ; save return address in Memory
    pop [ReturnPointer]

    ; call and replace with our own return point.
    call [rcx]

    mov rsp,[StackPointer]

    ; return to caller
    push [ReturnPointer]
    ret
FT_CallFunction ENDP
```

Comment: R8 and R9 are call-clobbered in both mainstream x86-64 calling conventions (x86-64 System V and Windows x64).  This looks like Windows x64; the call-preserved regs are RBX, RDI, RSI, RBP, RSP, and R12-R15.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-170#x64-register-usage